# Two-factor authentification incorrect code-flow for OpenIddict 2.0.1 and ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication, openiddict

I'm trying to make a two-factor authentication with flow:

1. First request with username/e-mail and password
2. Second request with authentication code from mobile app

I use OpeIddict library 2.0.1 which uses AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server for checking request processing.
According my flow I send in first request:

```
grant_type: 'password',
response_type: 'code',
client_id: 'mycliendid',
client_secret: '********',
username: 'user1',
password: '******',
scope: 'openid profile roles offline_access',
state: 'QRWDY8uGKRcv8S32NIL8XNHuNzL8BPauVDDnBU/n7FA='
```

It processes normally on server side wit 200 request and response with state code and authorization code:
`'nbj8FYHL4JGiEysbOhTgniVNZ/r9+QqCup6JWZxi0xA='`
Second request contains:

```
grant_type: 'authorization_code',
response_type: 'token',
redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5100/mainpage',
client_id: 'myclientid',
client_secret: '******'
code: 'nbj8FYHL4JGiEysbOhTgniVNZ/r9+QqCup6JWZxi0xA='
```

This request doesn't process in my code, it didn't pass on AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server side and returns me
`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The specified authorization code is invalid."}`

According the [IETF help](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)  authorization code flow don't need grant_type in first request, but I have to check username and password. If I delete grant_type in first request server returns me: `The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing`
I tried sent code like a '123456' in code field of second request from mobile app and it  doesn't work with same message   "*The specified authorization code is invalid.*"

What's the wrong actions in my side? Do you know? Struggling with it whole week

Comment: 1) your first request is a weird mixture of the password and authorization code flows (in the code flow, there's no grant_type, username, password, client_secret parameters in the authorization request). 2) enable logging in ASP.NET Core and change the default log level to Trace to see if there's any additional information.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Kevin. Additional logs returns me `The token request was rejected because the authorization code or the refresh token was invalid.` as I assumed. As my understanding I should make two flows: password flow with getting token and run second authorization code flow with token(access/refresh) or cockie to check a code?

Comment: If you want to support 2FA, the password flow is not an option (at least, not the standard flavor). Consider using the code flow exclusively.

Comment: Hmm, have I use authorization code flow with the checking login/password on the first stage? And if I don't send grant_type server returns me "The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing."

Comment: @SergeyFilippov did you find a solution to this, i want to do the same thing and struggling to find anything